# USB ports for 4G modules disappears after resetting the 4G module

Tags: uart, usb-hub

I am using the EC25 quectel LTE module with Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. I can access the internet using serial pins of raspberry pi i.e. UART Tx and Rx. I can find `ttyUSB[0-5]` in `ls \dev`. I am sending `AT` commands to the module using these serial ports. But whenever I am resetting the 4G module using its reset pin, 4G modules restarts properly but `ttyUSB*` is not in the list of `/dev`. I have to power off and power on again the 4G module and then ports are again there in the list.

Am I doing something wrong?  Please help me for following 2 issues:

1. Is there any way to get the ports again while the device is powered up already?
2. After every restart, Port numbers are changing. For ex, for the first time, I am getting 
   `ttyUSB0, ttyUSB1, ttyUSB2 and ttyUSB3`. Sometimes, I get `ttyUSB0, ttyUSB1, ttyUSB3 and ttyUSB4` and sometimes I even get `ttyUSB0, ttyUSB1, ttyUSB4 and ttyUSB5`. And I am using `ttyUSB2` and `ttyUSB3`. How to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The following posts might help: "Need consistent physical USB port to have same USB number":
https://lb.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=157930&sid=1976c51a37ba16236ac721fddf09bf8d. I have seen a couple of fixes, but sadly, none of which is simple.

Comment: Can you find some error messages in `journalctl`?

Comment: I couldn't undertand the full result from ```journalctl``` but I found a line saying ```usb1-1-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?``` But according to me, if this is the problem, then it should not run properly on power up.